# To access an account and make money transfer

Tags: united-states, scams

My friend working in Estonia now is going to pay a bill from his account in the USA and the server in Estonia is not working,  so he is asking me to do him a favour by giving me access to his account to make transfer to pay his bill. What shall I do? Is this legal?
Thank you in advance for the answer.

Comment: How long have you known this "friend", and have you ever met in person? This sounds like a scam.

Comment: If the server is not working, it won't help if your friend gives you access to the account. This has all the hallmarks of a scam.

Comment: "The server not working" may be legitimate, although perhaps incorrectly described. Many financial institutions have filtering on their online banking that blocks connections from unusual places. If the friend used to live in New York, and is now suddenly trying to log in from Estonia, it may well be true that they do not have access (but the login would work if it was in New York).

Comment: @dwizum Granted, but also worth noting that there would be legitimate ways to resolve that sort of issue, without involving a third party "friend" to get the bill paid.

Comment: @Steve-O Absolutely - as I explained in my answer. My point in commenting here was, it's a red herring and not an absolute guaranteed indicator that this is a scam.

Answer (score 2):

You asked,

> Is this legal?

There is likely no law preventing your friend from giving you his credentials, however it's almost 100% certain that your friend's financial institution has a user agreement regarding use of their online banking tools which prohibit your friend from sharing their credentials. Banks will sometimes take drastic measures if they detect this (such as removing that customer's access to online banking, or even dropping the customer all together) and many banks have sophisticated tools to detect when it does happen.

That said, the burden is on your friend, they're the ones breaking the user agreement - not you.

But more importantly than all that, any time personal info or financial details change hands, there's an implied level of trust that needs to be in place. Do you trust this person? How well do you know them? If, by "friend," you mean "someone I've known since childhood, who I would easily trust with my life" then you may already have a level of trust that makes this a non-issue.

But, when you say "friend," if you really mean "a stranger I met on Facebook who has been talking really nice to me, but I don't actually know them at all in real life" then this is almost certainly a scam, and you should treat it as such.

And, at the end of the day - you have to ask yourself, why isn't your friend taking a more conventional route to resolve their problem? If they have a legitimate bill, and a legitimate account at a bank, but they're having trouble accessing their account online, they could certainly call the bank and either make the payment over the phone, or troubleshoot their connectivity issues without your involvement.

Answer (score 2):

Unless you know the person from personal contact for longer, this is probably a scam.

What he will give you are *stolen credentials*, and you will transfer money out of some poor sods account onto the scammers account, and when the owner informs the police, guess who they will come to.

Answer (score 0):

> What shall I do?

Realise that your friend is not actually your friend and is trying to trick you into doing something illegal for their benefit. You are the fall-guy the police will arrest.

> Is this legal?

No.

Maybe the account details they will give you are details stolen from some victim. If you do as asked, you will log on to the victims account and perform the actual theft of the victims money. This crime will be traced to you.

Answer (score 0):

> pay a bill from his account in the USA and the server in Estonia is not working

What server?  If the US server is not working when your friend is in Estonia, then tell him to use a VPN with a server in the US.  The bank will then think he's in the US.

Otherwise, this smells very much like a scam.